# Excel vba error while capturing old value

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am getting an error when I am trying to capture an old value from a cell: 
run-time error '13' Type mismatch.

This is the code I am using:

```
Dim oldValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

oldValue = Target(1, 1).Value
MsgBox oldValue

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'check if one of the target columns is changed
If Target.Cells.Column = 6 Or Target.Cells.Column = 9 Or Target.Cells.Column = 10 Or Target.Cells.Column = 11 Then

'Set variables
    Dim LogActivity As String
    Dim cRow As Integer
    Dim pRowCount As Integer

    Dim wsPBS As Worksheet
    Dim wsHistoric As Worksheet

    Set wsPBS = Sheets("PBS")
    Set wsHistoric = Sheets("Historic")
    cRow = Target.Cells.Row
    pRowCount = wsHistoric.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Check for blanks on PBS sheet and exit if entry is not complete
    Dim BlankCount As Integer
    BlankCount = 0

    If wsPBS.Range("D" & cRow).Value = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
    If wsPBS.Range("E" & cRow).Value = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
    If wsPBS.Range("F" & cRow).Value = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
    If wsPBS.Range("H" & cRow).Value = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
    If wsPBS.Range("I" & cRow).Value = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
    If wsPBS.Range("J" & cRow).Value = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1

    If BlankCount >= 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        If Target.Cells.Column = 6 Then LogActivity = "Owner change"
        If Target.Cells.Column = 9 Then LogActivity = "Status change"
        If Target.Cells.Column = 10 Then LogActivity = "Priority change"
        If Target.Cells.Column = 11 Then LogActivity = "Completion rate"

    Range("C" & cRow & ":O" & cRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

    wsHistoric.Select
    wsHistoric.Range("F" & pRowCount).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wsHistoric.Range("A" & pRowCount).Value = Date
    wsHistoric.Range("B" & pRowCount).Value = Time
    wsHistoric.Range("C" & pRowCount).Value = Application.UserName
    wsHistoric.Range("D" & pRowCount).Value = LogActivity
    wsHistoric.Range("E" & pRowCount).Value = oldValue

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

End Sub
```

The value is supposed to be stored in a global dim called 'oldValue' so I can use it later on in my code. 
The cell I am clicking does contain a string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `Target.Value` in this case? Also it's not robust to assume that you'll only ever select a string, I'd declare that `As Variant` and then test its type.

Comment: are you changing more than one cell at a time? If so, `Target` will be a range containing more than one cell, and you won't be able to get a `value` from it

Comment: @GregViers well you will be able to get a `value`, but it will *not* be a string, but an array.

Comment: No, it's a single cell. I changed the string to a variant and added a Msgbox and it shows the correct, old, value. But when in the rest of the code I go to paste it, it changes to a different value.

When I select another value in the drop-down, the run-time error pops back up

Comment: Maybe share the rest of your code, what are you actually doing with `oldValue`?

Comment: I updated the question with the entire code, maybe I'm overlooking something silly here.

Comment: You're `Select`ing within the `Worksheet_Change` event. That fires the selection change event again. You need to disable events within the worksheet_change. Or even better, don't `Select`.

Comment: Makes sense... what was that syntax again? Application.EnableEvents = False?

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False`, and then `= True` at the end. But you don't need to `Select` at all: `Range("C" & cRow & ":O" & cRow).Copy`.

Comment: Thank you BigBen. I tried that and it's working like a charm now... Thank you very much!

Comment: @BigBen you should post an answer =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon added...

Answer (score 1):

**The main issue:**

You're `Select`ing within the `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Range("C" & cRow & ":O" & cRow).Select
Selection.Copy
```

That fires the `Selection_Change` event again, overwriting `oldValue`.

No need to `Select` here. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

```
Range("C" & cRow & ":O" & cRow).Copy
```

---

**The secondary (yet still very important issue):**

In your original version of the selection change:

```
Dim oldValue As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

This will throw a type mismatch error if `Target` doesn't contain a `String` or something that can be coerced to a `String`.

In your instance, that was because `Target` actually was multiple cells: `Range("C" & cRow & ":O" & cRow)`.
But your code would also throw an error if you selected a cell with an error value (`#N/A`, `#DIV/0`, etc.).

---

**The fix:**

First of all, avoid using `Select`, as already noted.

If for some (rare) reason you absolutely need to `Select`, then toggle events off and on:

```
Private Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ... do your stuff
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Lastly, within the selection change, instead of assuming that you'll only select a string, or only select one cell, add some validation.

```
Dim oldValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub ' ignore a multi-cell selection
    If IsError(Target.Value) Then Exit Sub ' ignore selection of errors

    oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try identifying a single cell withing `Target`:

```
oldValue = Target(1,1).Value
```

Comment: This will still throw a type mismatch error if `Target` does not contain a string or something that can be coerced to a string. E.g. if the cell contains an error.

Comment: That gives me the 1st row/ column value in the paste... However clicking the cell still does show the old value. So not sure why it's not saving correctly.

Comment: I updated the question with the entire code, maybe I'm overlooking something silly here.